# Linear kernel SVM performs well on non-linear separable data

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

I am working on an exercise for my course in SVMs. We are given a 2D-dataset and we are supposed to construct a SVM model that classifies the data as good as possible. When I plot the training set it is clear that the data is not linearly separable. I then constructed a LS-SVM model with linear kernel, where I tune the parameters to obtain optimal performance, and went on to plot the ROC-curve of this model on the test set. The area under the ROC-curve is very close to 1, meaning that the model is almost a perfect classifier. What is the intuition behind this? FYI: I obtain similar results for polynomial and RBF kernels. [image]

[image]

Comment: plotting the decision boundary for the classifiers would be helpful in diagnosing the problem.  Note that for an RBF kernel you also need to tune the kernel parameter - if the kernel parameter is too small (or too large depending on the implementation) the kernel will be insensitive and you will just get a linear classifier again.  IIRC a inhomogenous fourth order polynomial kernel ought to work quite well on this dataset.

Comment: A perfect ROC AUC is not the same as a high ROC AUC. You can draw a line that does a good-but-imperfect job of separating the two classes. There doesn't seem to be any inconsistency here.

Comment: @Sycorax,  I know it is a good classifier but not a perfect one. My question is more aimed at the fact that the linear kernel model performs equally well as the RBF kernel on data that is not linearly separable. I always assumed RBF kernel models are more fit to model data that is non-linear.

Comment: You'll need to tune all of the parameters of the RBF kernel to get perfect training set accuracy.